# PyCharm says "Python version 3 does not support a 'F' prefix"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to run a python program with pycharm and I have this line of code:

```
for i, o in enumerate(outputs):
    f.write(f'#Output{i + 1}\t{o}\n')
```

The IDE marks the f inside the write function stating this error:
"Python version 3 does not support a 'F' prefix".

Can anyone help?

I also have a problem that for some reason numpy package install does not succeed. Maybe that has any connection?

Comment: the ide said so, but is there any error when you try running this code?

Comment: what version of python3? f string only appeared from 3.6

Comment: I'm not sure so that must be it. anyone has a guide of how to change version in pycharm?

Comment: Look for the Python interpreter settings in Pycharm Preference

Comment: Did you try googling the error message? I found some existing posts like [Wrong Python version in PyCharm's inspections](/q/49820407/4518341), [Setting the project interpreter in PyCharm to Python 3.7 causes spurious code incompatibility messages about Python 3.5](/q/52636098/4518341), and [How do I stop pycharm from complaining about F string in python 2.7, Im using python 3](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000419930). I don't use PyCharm so I don't know if any of them solve the problem, but they should at least give you an idea of where to look.